# Is it possible to automate build settings in a Cordova iOS plugin?

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I need to add a *"Header Search Path"* and a linker flag to the XCode build when a plugin is installed. Is it possible to manipulate build settings in the plugin.xml to automate the process?

Specifically, I want to add `$(SDKROOT)/usr/include/libxml2` to *"Header Search Paths"* and `-lxml2` to *"Other Linker Flags"*

Comment: Did you find a solution to this other than what @Ally provided?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a library as a source file:
`<source-file src="libxml2.a" framework="true" />`

But it's not currently possible to automatically install with a linker flag sorry.